# automatic update of filename for read.csv in r

Tags: r, paste, readxl

I run a monthly data import process in R, using something similar to this:

```
Data <- read.csv("c:/Data/March 2018 Data.csv")
```

However, I want to fully automate the process and, hence, find a way to change the date of the file being uploaded, in this case 'March 2018', using a variable from a lookup table. This lookup table is changed every month externally and the Date variable, which indicates the month of production, is updated during this.

I've tried to use paste() function, but didn't get very  far:

```
Data <- read.csv(paste("C:/Data Folder",Date,"Data.csv"))
```

Keeps saying "No such file or directoryError in file". I've checked the file names and path are fine. The only issue I'm detecting is the code line in the directory appears like this

```
'c:/Data folder/ March 2018 Data.csv'
```

I'm not sure if that extra 'space' is the issue

Any ideas?

Comment: Try naming it without black spaces.

Comment: How do I do that when the Date variable doesn't have any space before or after it. It's literally just "March 2018". I'm not adding the space intentionally, gets generated when I use the above formulae

Comment: You can use `sep=""` inside the paste call to prevent it from printing extra whitespace. Alternatively, you can use `paste0`, which uses `sep=""` by default.

Comment: Worked a treat, thanks to both jalazbe and bobble

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both bobbel and jalazbe for this solution

I used paste0()

```
Data <- read.csv(paste0("c/Date folder/",Date,"Data.csv"))
```